# How can I convert a 'pp3' dot pattern into an 'im' object in spatstat?

Tags: r, spatstat

My goal is to create an `im` object from terrain elevation data (`pp3`'s *z*-axis), similar to `bei.extra` (`$elev` and `$grad`).  I started by creating a `pp3` object from my data set:

```r
x <- elev_test$x
y <- elev_test$y
z <- elev_test$z
X <- pp3(x, y, z, c(0, 102), c(0, 152), c(90, 102))
plot(X)
```

[image]

Then I tried to coerce the `pp3` object to class `im`, but `as.im` threw an error:

```
> Elev_im <- as.im(X)
Error in as.im.default(X) : Can't convert X to a pixel image
```

How can I obtain the desired `im` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conversion functions like `as.im` are designed to convert data from one format to another format that represents the same information.

You are trying to infer the spatial height of a surface from a sample of *(x,y,z)* sample points. That's not a conversion between formats; that is some kind of interpolation.

I suggest you create a two-dimensional point pattern using the *(x,y)* coordinates for the locations, and use the *z* coordinates as marks of this pattern. Then smooth the marks to obtain a surface.

Something like:

```
X <- ppp(elev_test$x, elev_test$y, c(0, 102), c(0, 152), marks=elev_test$z)
Z <- Smooth(X)
```

Then you can try different arguments to `Smooth.ppp` to get the best interpolant.

Another possibility would be to use `nnmark` instead of `Smooth.ppp` to obtain a surface consisting of small flat pieces (this would be better if your points come from a rice paddy field). You'll have to make these decisions yourself as the computer is not wise enough.

Comment: Great, I got it. Thanks a lot for the help. I have just one more question, if I also want to calculate the slope (equal to bei.extra$grad), is it possible to do this only in spatstat? I tried for a few hours in different ways via raster, but I can't convert back to some kind of spatstat object.

Answer (score 0):

About creating an object similar to bei.extra$grad, with an area slope map, I think I found a solution, via raster:

1. add my data with x, y and z coordinates in *ArcGis* software;
2. I created the 2D Elevation of the terrain;
3. I calculated the terrain slope [`slope`] and exported the `tif` [`raster`] map.

Finally, in `R`:

```
#import raster (tif)
r<-raster("Slope_raster12.tif")
#convet raster in im class 
sppp<-as.im(r)
plot(sppp, axes=T)
```

[image: slope in %.]

Note: slope in %.